# In aspx page how to bind only one json value inside a tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, aspx-user-control

I have a problem I have JSON data in my aspx page.Also I have code inside code behind to call api to get all JSON data. My sample json data as follows`enter

 "tags": "খালেদা-জিয়া,বিএনপি,নির্বাচন",
            "timeline_tags": null,
            "people_tags": null,`

Here you can see in tags there are more than 1 value. I want display the first value .In my aspx I take inside a tag as follows

```
`enter code here`<a href="/TagNews.aspx?tagname=<%#Eval("tags")%>" class="tags">
```

Here in #EVAL i get all value i need to get the first one.Your help will be highly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: you can split the string, I guess. The service which generated the JSON ought to have returned the data as an array, really.

Comment: I got an idea to replace ',' with '' but still problem i could not delete the remaining string 'বিএনপি,নির্বাচন'  i want to show only the first one "খালেদা-জিয়া"

Comment: Now I bind like this <%#((string)Eval("tags")).Replace(",", "")%>

Comment: Like I said, _split_ the string into an array (i.e. using String.Split) and use only the first element in the returned array. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx . Replace only alters parts of a string, it doesn't split it into sections.

Comment: Yes I got it it works in codebehind but how I can use array in eval in aspx and String.Split . I need to do in aspx page. How to do that ? Thanks in Advance

Comment: And please Don't mind I'm not an expert in ASP.NET so I ask ..

Comment: Same as any other method, by using the return value. Something like this I think: `<%#((string)Eval("tags")).Split(new string[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.None)[0]%>`

Comment: Ohh!!! Thanks Dear it works finally.

Comment: No problem. I wrote it as the answer - please mark as accepted - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string and use just the first returned element:

```
<%#((string)Eval("tags")).Split(new string[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.None)[0]%>
```